# ¿Cómo obtengo el valor de un objeto que se usará para calcular operaciones?

Tags: angular, typescript

Estoy tratando de obtener cada objeto en mi matriz `data`, porque en ese momento está imprimiendo completamente el valor de mis`datos` y solo necesito obtener un objeto (`calculo_impuesto, cantidad_factura_pivote, costo_factura_pivote`) de `data[obj]`:

Entonces, en este punto estoy haciendo un servicio (que obtiene los valores de `datos` y por lo tanto de mi constructor hago la solicitud respectiva para obtenerlos y luego los uso en mi componente), así`this.calcularDatos(data) ;`es solo una llamada 'pivote' a la función en la que quiero realizar los cálculos de suma o multiplicación.

---

**SERVICE**

```
  public obtenerProducto()
  {
    return new Promise(
      resolve=>{
        this.http.get('authentication/consultarProductoFactura.php')
        .subscribe(
        data => resolve(data)
        )
      }
    )
  };
```

**COMPONENT**

```
  refrescarDatos()
  {
    this._serviceFacturacion.obtenerProducto()
    .then(data=>{
      this.listaProducto= data;
      this.obtenerProducto();
      this.calcularDatos(data);
    })
    .catch(err=>{
      console.log(err);
    });
  };

  calcularDatos(data)
  {
    Object.keys(data).forEach(obj =>
    {
       //Si solo pongo este valor, imprime todos los valores del objeto (como es esperado)
       console.log(data[obj]);

       //Esto a manera de ejemplo, se que es un valor erroneo
       console.log(data[obj.costo_factura_pivote])
       console.log(data[obj.cantidad_factura_pivote])

       //Despues de tener los valores, tengo que calcular:
       subtotal += costo_factura_pivote *  cantidad_factura_pivote;
    });
  };
```

---

**OBJETO**

```
  Object 
  { 
    calculo_impuesto: "1.19"
​    cantidad_factura_pivote: "2"
​    cantidad_minima_producto: "5"
​    codigo_producto: "COD002"
​    costo_factura_pivote: "430000"
​    costo_venta_producto: "430000"
​    descuento_factura_pivote: "0"
​    fecha_factura_pivote: "2018-09-14"
​    id_empresa_factura_pivote: "1"
​    id_factura_pivote: "1"
​    id_impuesto: "4"
​    id_impuesto_producto: "4"
​    id_producto: "2"
​    nombre_impuesto: "IVA"
​    nombre_producto: "Dymo 450"
​    valor_impuesto: "19"
 }
```

**CONSOLE**

[image: Console]

**¿POR QUÉ?**

Porque, necesito obtener el subtotal, calcular los impuestos y el descuento de mi factura. En este caso son 3 elementos de esa factura, tal vez puede ser más. Entonces, teniendo eso, ¿cómo se puede calcular una suma (costos) de esos objetos, por ejemplo de: (costo_factura_pivote)?

Estoy tratando de obtener el subtotal de cada objeto obtenido de mi servicio, por ejemplo: Tengo productos dos, producto A (costo 10 USD) (cantidad: 20 unidades), producto B (costo 15 USD) (cantidad: 10 unidades) ), entonces, necesito sumar ambos valores:

Producto A = 10 USD * 20 unidades> 200 USD

Producto B = 15 USD * 10 unidades> 150 USD

```
(costo_factura_pivote *  cantidad_factura_pivote)
```

**Subtotal (A,B) = 350 USD**

Y posteriormente mostrar dichos valores en mi vista:
[image: Lista]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomando como ejemplo tu codigo, creo que lo que tenes que hacer es:

```
            calcularDatos(data: array<any>)
            {
                let producto: number;
                let subTotal: number = 0;
                Object.keys(data).forEach(obj =>
                {
                    producto = 0;
                    //Asi imprimiras el valor del costo_factura_pivote de ese indice
                    console.log(data[obj].costo_factura_pivote);

                    //Asi imprimiras el valor del cantidad_factura_pivote de ese indice
                    console.log(data[obj].cantidad_factura_pivote);

                    producto = data[obj].costo_factura_pivote * data[obj].cantidad_factura_pivote;

                    console.log('Costo del Producto => $' + producto);

                    subtotal = subtotal + producto;
                });

                console.log('Un subTotal de => $' + subtotal);
            };
```